# is there a format to assign multiple variables in a single line of code if it goes beyond the 88 character max length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to assign multiple variables based on multiple fields on a single csv line. however, the variable names go far beyond the 88 character max length in black formatter. Is there a way to format it in a similar way you can format a long string into a multi-line block or do i have to create individual lines for each variable?

example:

instead of:

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k, l = line.split()`

is it possible to do something like:

`{a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    h, j, k, l} = line.split()`

or do i have to do:

`a = line.split()[0]
   b = line.split()[1]
   c = line.split()[2]
   ...
   l = line.split()[10]`

Comment: *"is it possible to do something like:..."* Yes, but use parentheses instead of curly braces.

Comment: thanks! that worked just fine.

Comment: Square brackets would also work here, but I'd consider parentheses to be more idiomatic.